# Is my theory behind the integral correct (using sums of integrals)?

Tags: integration

Lets say that you are trying to calculate the integral $$\int_{-\infty}^0  f(x) dx$$

For one thing, I don't know what this integral is, so I can't use knowledge to solve this one.

Theory:

We can solve this by doing the following $$\int_{-\infty}^0 f(x)dx=\int_{-1}^0 f(x)dx+\int_{-2}^{-1} f(x)dx\int_{-3}^{-2} f(x)dx\cdots$$

Is this true? The reason I am unsure of my theory is that when I google the integral of $f(x)=\frac{1}{x!}$ it comes out as a different value than what my theory generates. Help?

Comment: the first thing you want to talk about before discussing the validity of your formula would be whether the integral converges

Comment: go to the $$\lim_{p\to\infty}\int_{-p}^0f(x)dx$$